# scons setting CXXFLAGS in one module affects another one

Tags: c++, build-process, scons

in dirA/SConscript I have:

```
Import('env')
probeenv = env.Clone()
probeenv['CXXFLAGS'] +=  ['-fno-rtti','-Wnon-virtual-dtor']
... stuff that uses probeenv
```

in dirB/SConscript I have

```
Import('env')
sipenv = env.Clone()
... stuff that uses sipenv
```

Now, c++ files in dirB that gets compiled, gets the CXXFLAGS from dirA - how come ?
This does not happen with CCFLAGS. Nor does it happen if I use `probeenv['CXXFLAGS'] =  ['-fno-rtti','-Wnon-virtual-dtor']` in dirA

Comment: which version of scons are you using? Although I've seen things like this in older versions of scons, more recent versions have much better isolation between environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a scons bug if CXXFLAGS is not set in "main" SConstruct. The workaround is to simply set it to an empty list there.

SConscript:

```
env['CXXFLAGS'] = []
```

Answer (score 1):

There is dedicated method to append data to various compiler flags:

```
probenv.Append(CXXFLAGS = ['-fno-rtti','-Wnon-virtual-dtor'])
```

There is also AppendUnique and AppendENVPath. See the man for description.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this is:

```
env.Prepend(CXXFLAGS = ['-fno-rtti', '-Wnon-virtual-dtor'])
```

Like this, you don't get an error and you avoid a workaround, because if the `CXXFLAGS` value is not set, it is created automaticaly.